# AdSense revenue on 'Conversions' tab doesn't match Adsense revenue on 'AdSense' tab in Google Analytics Experiments

Tags: google-analytics, adsense, ab-testing

I'm running an AB test via Google Analytics Experiments. I've set the success metric to be AdSense revenue. However, when I look at the experiment data (I'm about a day in so far) there is a mismatch between the revenue reported by the 'Conversions' tab (on which the experiment is being assessed) and the revenue being reported on the AdSense tab.

The conversions tab reports less than £0.01 for A and £0.00 for B, whereas the AdSense tab reports $0.21 and $0.45 respectively (yes, they report in two different currencies).

Any ideas why they are so different?